# How to use Firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase

I want to create an android app, I read that firebase can help me with this. What is firebase and how to use it with my reference?

Comment: Please use google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase helps you with a lot of features like:

- Authentication (Anonymous accounts, Google/Facebook/Twitter/GitHub
  Sign in)
- Saving data through the Realtime Database
- Storing files
- Get crash reports (if your app crashes on ones device you will see an error log in Firebase)
- Notifications
- App Indexing
- Dynamic links
- Invites
- Test Lab
- Many more features

Source: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

Of course the list of features it offers is much bigger than that.

To get started on android development with Firebase look here:
[Firebase Android Get Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)